# Can any tell me if I am right (integration)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$\int^2_0\dfrac{(2x^{1/2}-1)}{((x+1-2x^{1/2})^{0.5}+x^{0.5})}\,dx$

I felt like I solve this question correctly, but when I checked the answer with my calculator TI-nspire CAS it gave me 4/3 , and wolframapha also gave me 4/3.   Isnt it supposed to be 2. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is difficult to read. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Luckily you didn't attach a picture. [Pictures may not be legible](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189),
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.  If you want someone to check your work, it's better to ask [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+of+((2x%5E(1%2F2)-1)%2F((x%2B1-2x%5E(1%2F2))%5E0.5%2Bx%5E0.5))+from+0+to+2).

Comment: You're right.  $$\begin{align}
\int^2_0\frac{(2x^{1/2}-1)}{((x+1-2x^{1/2})^{0.5}+x^{0.5})}\,dx&=\int_0^{\sqrt2}\frac{2u(2u-1)}{u+\sqrt{u^2-2u+1}}\,du\\\\
&=\int_0^{\sqrt2}\frac{2u(2u-1)}{u+u-1}\,du\\\\
&=2
\end{align}$$

Comment: However, when you graph this question you will know that the answer is 1.3333 instead of 2.

Answer (score 4):

The moral of the story here is that $\sqrt{\rm thing^2} = |\rm thing|$, which necessitates some care when you're working where the $\rm thing$ is negative.

Using $u$-substitution with $u = \sqrt{x}$, you do indeed get the integral

$$\int_0^\sqrt2 \frac{2u(2u - 1)\ du}{\sqrt{u^2 - 2u + 1} + u}$$

However, the issue is that $$\sqrt{u^2 - 2u + 1} = \sqrt{(u - 1)^2} = |u - 1| = \begin{cases}u - 1, & u \ge 1 \\ -(u - 1), &u < 1\end{cases}$$

with $u = 1$ in the interval $[0, \sqrt{2}]$ over which you're integrating.

Thus, you'll have to split the integral up into

$$\int_0^\sqrt2 \frac{2u(2u - 1)\ du}{\sqrt{u^2 - 2u + 1} + u} = \int_0^1 \frac{2u(2u - 1)\ du}{-(u - 1) + u} + \int_1^\sqrt{2} \frac{2u(2u - 1)\ du}{u - 1 + u}$$

which does indeed give the expected value of $\frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: That's right. I forgot about this fact. Thank you so much :)